# New install of STS 3.3.0 does not connect to existing projects in SVN repository

Tags: svn, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I installed STS 3.3.0 and did an import from my old workspace to bring in an existing spring web project.  When I right-click on the project and select TEAM, all I get is 'Apply Patch'.

I don't see the normal long list of options of commit, update, synchronize etc.

I have one other project that SVN does recognize but that's one out of a dozen or so.  The rest just say 'Apply Patch'.

I upgraded to STS 3.3.0 for the immediate reason that I dropped my PC and the only application that would not work afterwards was STS 2.9.2 (Crazy).  I put on the newest version of STS but can't reconnect SVN to my projects, even though I imported them.

Any suggestions?  I feel like now I'm operating without a net until I get this resolved.

Thanks,

Comment: is the SVN team connector not installed or broken? If I remember that correctly you usually install a Team Connector and an implmenetation (Subversive + SVNkit).

Comment: I imagine it's broken... could I simply reinstall it?  I might need a tip on what it's called, etc.

Comment: if you can re-attach (or just share the project again) then the team provider is not broken. it's only important the .svn folders are intact. talking about .svn folders: the working copy was made with the same svn version you use in eclipse? if you checkout using svn 1.7 the team provider for 1.6 will not be able to use that.

Comment: I've just tried the 3.3 version. there is no SVN team provider installed by default. You can just add Subclipse or Subversive via the Marketplace. That should already do the trick :)

Comment: I added Subclipse as you suggested, @wemu earlier.  One project I imported and connected to SVN just fine... but the rest just have 'Apply patch' showing.  Also... where might I look to know what version of team provider I'm using.